# Add rows to DataGridView based on TextBox text

Tags: vb.net

I need to add a quantity of rows based on a number in a textbox. If I put a number in a textbox that quantity of rows will be added.

For example, `Textbox.Text = "7"` yields 7 new rows

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might look something like:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim numRows As Integer
    If Integer.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, numRows) Then
        If (numRows >= 1) Then
            For i As Integer = 1 To numRows
                DataGridView1.Rows.Add()
            Next
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Value: " & TextBox1.Text, "Number of Rows must be Greater Than or Equal to 1")
        End If
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Value: " & TextBox1.Text, "Invalid Integer")
    End If
End Sub
```